# how to find peak value of the week from table in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with operations,which looks like this:

```
    date value
01.12.20 1100
04.12.20 920
09.12.20 350
18.12.20 5000
```

and i need to find **peak value of every week for last n-weeks.** **So expected result should looks like:**

```
    week value_sum
  week 1 1100
  week 2 350
  week 3 5000
```

i've tried it to separete for groups:

```
select
    trunc(mydate, 'ww') week,
    sum(myvalue) value_sum

from myTABLE
    where 1=1
    and mydate >=date'2020-12-01'
    and mydate < date'2021-01-01'

group by
    trunc(mydate, 'ww')
    having max(sum(myvalue))
```

and this to get days for last 7-weeks for ex, which i can use as:

```
WITH date_range as
    (select trunc(sysdate,'WW')-(rownum-1)*7 week
        from (select rownum from dual)
        connect by level <=13
        order by 1)
select * from date_range
```

so how can i solve my problem?

Comment: How is "2020" the peak value?  It is not even in the data?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Yes, you're right, fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the max value - it represents the peak, your first query with a modification of the sum->max will do the job, with a reduction to the having clause.

```
select
    trunc(mydate, 'ww') week,
    max(myvalue) value_sum

from myTABLE
    where 1=1
    and mydate >=date'2020-12-01'
    and mydate < date'2021-01-01'

group by
    trunc(mydate, 'ww')
```

Comment: max value of the day of the week. so first i nedd to sum up values per day, then group by weeks and then choose the peak=max value between sum of days per week. so this solution not works perfect for me.

Comment: @Kurasao, nothing in sample data nor initial message you posted suggests what you've commented. Therefore, this **does** return result you wanted (though, if `ww` is modified to `iw`). Weeks we're talking about are 49,50 and 51 (not 1, 2, 3 as your expected result suggests). Sample data is just too *poor*; what "sum up values per day"? Which "day"? All days you posted are different from each other. I suggest you massively rewrite the original question and make it much more clear to people who're willing to assist.